# API -> create reusable function to getAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, rest

Dears,
I'm just wondering if it is possible to create one function which takes SQL query as argument and will proceed with request. Considering two functions:

```
async addExpense(req, res){
    const addExpense ='INSERT INTO budget.expenses_category_assigned_to_user VALUES(DEFAULT, $1, $2)'

    if(!req.body.name){
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Expense cannot be added. Name is missing'})
    }

    const queryValues = [
        req.user.id,
        req.body.name
    ]

    try{
        await db.query(addExpense, queryValues)
        return res.status(200).json({message: 'Expense has been successfully added'})
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).send({message: err})
    }
}
```

```
async addPaymentMethod(req, res){
    const addQuery = 'INSERT INTO budget.payment_methods_assigned_to_user VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, $2)'

    if(!req.body.name){
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Payment method has not been added'})
    }

    try{
        const queryParams = [
            req.user.id,
            req.body.name
        ]

        await db.query(addQuery, queryParams)
        return res.status(200).send({message: `${req.body.name} has been added`})
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).send({message: err})
    }
}
```

Despite a few differences they could be easily standarized and only parameter that can change are query  and queryValues.
Could you please advise if it is possible in Node and postgres to create such function:

```
foo(query, queryParams){
 action
}
```

which will proceed with the request and can be reused for multiple endpoints ?
The idea is avoiding redundancy and keep REST API functionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, indeed I misunderstood your question. My idea below basically

- segregate out the query into seperrate
- call respective query in the 'addOne' function, based on the argument 'table' that pass in from the endpoint entry function
- call 'addOne' function in the endpoint with correct argument that defined in the 'addOne' function

Hope this answer you question

```
async addExpense(req, res){
  addOne(req, res, 'Expense')
}

async addPaymentMethod(req, res){
  addOne(req, res, 'Payment method')
}

async function addOne(req, res, table) {

  if(!req.body.name){
      return res.status(400).send({message: 'Expense cannot be added. Name is missing'})
  }

  try{
    switch (table) {
      case 'Expense':
        await addExpensesQuery(req)
        break;
      case 'Payment method':
        await addPaymentQuery(req)
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unsupported operation')
    }
      return res.status(200).json({message: `${table} has been successfully added`})
  }catch(err){
      return res.status(400).send({message: err})
  }
}

function addExpensesQuery (req) {
  const addExpense ='INSERT INTO budget.expenses_category_assigned_to_user VALUES(DEFAULT, $1, $2)'
  const queryValues = [
    req.user.id,
    req.body.name
  ]
  return db.query(addExpense, queryValues)
}

function addPaymentQuery (req) {
  const addQuery = 'INSERT INTO budget.payment_methods_assigned_to_user VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, $2)'
  const queryValues = [
    req.user.id,
    req.body.name
  ]
  return db.query(addQuery, queryValues)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is not a good idea to dynamically generate query for different table in one endpoint. You may have hard time in the future when one of the table has added/removed column(s), you may have hard to maintain that piece of code, and you might break another query when fixing this query

Comment: Mr. J the idea is not to generate dynamically generate query but rather avoid creation similar function. Based on my example you can see that general difference is different SQL query and possibility of passing different params to query. The rest is exactly the same. I am wondering if it is possible to have function addOne (which always will add one thing such as expense, income, paymentMethod). Main body will be always very similar. Only two differences would be params and query. Is that clear right now ?